# Bootstrap Carosel Text on the side

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap carousel plugin and here is the code I have right now. http://pastie.org/8731842 . I was looking to improve the carousel by moving the text to the right side. http://screencloud.net/v/35KC (you can see the example on http://kickstarter.com).  I made a makeshift version like this http://pastie.org/8731851 But its not exactly what I want. I want the sidebar to control the carousel. It is pretty similar to kickstarters carousel (the links on the right).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Just some styling edits. Here is the added CSS.

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
  padding-left: 300px;
}
.carousel-caption {
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 300px;
}
.carousel-inner > .item.active > img,
.carousel-inner > .item.active > a > img {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.carousel-control.left {
  left: 315px;
}
```